# Are nonsensical lyrics common in Spanish lyrics?

Tags: traducción

Based on the answer given [to my other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/jumping-between-pronunciations-of-y-in-spanish-songs), I'd like to know if it's common to have completely nonsensical lyrics in Spanish music. I know English music has some ridiculous lyrics, but generally popular music tends to stay decipherable. But while trying to translate Sharkira's Rabiosa ([YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OO1pOqRJkA)), I was completely lost. Reading a [forum posting](http://www.shakiraholics.org/board/showthread.php?s=26a932bd07c1b5bb0afd44fbf41ec0ee&threadid=8994), it looks like the song is confusing for everyone.

My question: is this a style or genre in Spanish music, is the song actually decipherable, or is this just one case of a gibberish song?

Comment: Many English songs are completely confusing or nonsensical as well.  If you don't believe me, just ask The Walrus.

Comment: Pop songs are all full of gibberish lyrics. People don't care. A lot of times it's just the rhythm and music that matters to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say nonsensical lyrics, but at least they make some grammatical sense, and may not make much sense in the semantic aspect.

But after all, song lyrics are a form of poetry, and I've seen poem verses that are just enumerations of nouns or adjectives, so it's not strange that some lyrics take also some liberties from the language.

Answer (score 3):

Shakira is known for having songs that are impossible to understand. I remember some comedy shows where they joked about how she might need a translator wherever she speaks to translate from "Shakirian" to Spanish.